# Sqlite 3.7.10 and static linking in Delphi

Tags: delphi, sqlite, linker

Latest version of Sqlite (3.7.10) wanted to link __msize function and since Delphi memory manager can not report the size of a memory block, I had to introduce a hack (d5 compatible)

```
function __msize(p: pointer): Cardinal;cdecl;
begin
  Result:=PInteger(integer(p)-4)^-6;
end;
```

Are there other solutions inside Sqlite (defines?) or Delphi to fix this so no undocumented features are used.

Comment: I think I'd be inclined to find the C code that wants to use `msize` and try to remove it if possible. I thought `msize` was an MSVC special in any case.

Comment: This hack won't work with the newer heap manager (FastMM4), I suspect. You should better rely on our answer below.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Around line # 15195 in the source code, comment the following lines:

```
/*
** Windows systems have malloc_usable_size() but it is called _msize()
*/
#if !defined(HAVE_MALLOC_USABLE_SIZE) && SQLITE_OS_WIN
# define HAVE_MALLOC_USABLE_SIZE 1
# define malloc_usable_size _msize
#endif
```

into

```
/*
** Windows systems have malloc_usable_size() but it is called _msize()
#if !defined(HAVE_MALLOC_USABLE_SIZE) && SQLITE_OS_WIN
# define HAVE_MALLOC_USABLE_SIZE 1
# define malloc_usable_size _msize
#endif
*/
```

It will disable the memory reuse of SQLite3 malloc, and will rely on the better FastMM4 reallocmem() implementation.

See [this commit](http://synopse.info/fossil/info/1865cf8a0b) e.g. for our Open Source implementation of SQLite3 static linking.

**Additional information:**

I think that we'd get rid of this issue in 3.7.11, as stated [by this commit](http://www.sqlite.org/src/info/238e35a441): a new `SQLITE_WITHOUT_MSIZE` global symbol will be added, and will be able to build the amalgamation source code without changing its content, just by setting the appropriate `SQLITE_WITHOUT_MSIZE` define. In the meanwhile, the easiest is to comment the above lines.

Comment: +1 This is what I was thinking of in my comment. Of course it seems Maksee is on D5 with the old Borland MM.

Comment: Thanks, I did some research in parallel, but anyway you posted a good answer

Comment: @Maksee I recommend you switch from the delphi Borland memory manager into [using FastMM4](http://sourceforge.net/projects/fastmm). It speeds up the application a lot, especially when it comes with database handling (a statically linked SQLite3 engine will be *much* faster), objects allocation, and string processing. And you'll find some nice features, like memory leak reporting. It works like a charm with Delphi 5.

Comment: @Arnaud, can you sample an SQL query that will be much faster with FastMM? I saw that sqlite usually is very modest in memory requesting so even with amazingly fast memory manager I doubt it can affect the performance that much. Although thanks for your advice, I will probably try this approach

Comment: When I insert 10000 rows of data within a transaction, FastMM4 makes the process much faster. It is at least what our regression tests show in our mORMot framework. And also retrieving of data is faster. Just try it, you'll be convinced.

Comment: Probably it depends. My tests, memory db, create ..[id], [txt] TEXT,.. Insert (Txt) Values (..50 symbols), you get the idea :) insert 100,000 times, default manager 3.454 sec, FastMM 3.154. Not a big deal in this particular case.

Comment: I'm using a SSD - so that's perhaps why my tests show a bigger difference. HD is not the bottleneck any more. And it will depend on how you create the data: are you measuring the time only within SQLite3, or are you taking in account the time needed to create the data?

Comment: Ok, I get the idea, anyway, I have FastMM nearby, so maybe from time to time many for good I will use it. Thanks

Comment: If you use to concatenate strings (like  `s := s+'something'`), FastMM4 will be much faster: its reallocation mechanism is much better than Borland's old MM algorithm.

Answer (score 2):

You can use SizeOfMem from JCL [JclSysUtils](http://jcl.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/jcl/trunk/jcl/source/common/JclSysUtils.pas?revision=2692&view=markup#l_277) unit.